# Altered compose function

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am wondering for a while now what is f. Could someone provide an example to how I should be running this function?
(Note: I understand that the (.) is function composition and I know what function composition if)

```
-- compose a function n >= 0 times with itself
composeN :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
composeN 0 f = id
composeN n f = f . (composeN (n-1) f)
```

Comment: Also without recursion: `composeN n f = appEndo $ mconcat (replicate n (Endo f))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f` is an arbitrary function, provided by the user. I could supply `composeN` with `succ`, to increment an integer, and have it be composed three times and applied to 2, thereby adding 3:

```
ghci> composeN 3 succ 2
5
```

Comment: I just figured it out. Two seconds before your post. Thanks :)